# Is inetutils not included in Debian or Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, syslog, inetd

Is inetutils or some programs in it provided or installed by default in Debian or Ubuntu? If not, why does Debian or Ubuntu not include it? Is it because they have better alternative programs in other packages? For example,

- inetd is included in inetutils, and it is not found on Ubuntu or Debian. What similar program is installed in Debian or Ubuntu by default?
- syslogd is included in inetutils. Does Debian or Ubuntu use rsyslogd instead? Which package does rsyslogd belong to?

Comment: Why should they be installed by default? O.o

Answer (score 1):

By default `inetutils*` it is not installed in Debian or Ubuntu.

The alternative to `inetd` may be [`xinetd`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/xinetd) or [`rlinetd`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/rlinetd). as the definition of the package say: `replacement for inetd with many enhancements`

`rsyslog`  provide the `rsyslogd` (`/usr/sbin/rsyslogd`)

The `rsyslog` come with the `rsyslog.service`, it is enabled by default.

To answer the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643605/is-inetutils-not-included-in-debian-or-ubuntu/643611?noredirect=1#comment1205346_643611):

`bsdutils` provide `logger` (`/usr/bin/logger`)

`openbsd-inetd` provide the `inetd`.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why inetutils is not chosen by Debian or Ubuntu?

Comment: @Ben I don't know exactly why inetd isn't chosen by Debian.

Comment: Are `syslogd` and `inetd` normally provided by inetutils? (`logger` is provided by both inetutils and util-linux, but seems to be normally by util-linux in Debian)

Comment: @Ben See my edit please.

Comment: How about `syslogd`?

Comment: Are syslogd (and logger, and inetd) provided by different packages the same or different implementations?